# How should controls be set up for jqPlot and JSON data in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jqplot

I'm currently working with jqPlot for the first time and finding it difficult find any information on how to set up the control for a barchart. So far I have been able to set up the linegraph and pie chart examples but the barchart has stumped me.

```
        public ActionResult PieChart()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult PieChartJSON()
    {
        List<PieChartData> sampleData = new List<PieChartData>();
        PieChartData test = new PieChartData();
        PieChartData test2 = new PieChartData();
        PieChartData test3 = new PieChartData();
        PieChartData test4 = new PieChartData();
        PieChartData test5 = new PieChartData();

        test.Label = "tara";
        test.Value = 3;
        sampleData.Add(test);

        test2.Label = "becky";
        test2.Value = 5;
        sampleData.Add(test2);

        test3.Label = "gareth";
        test3.Value = 3;
        sampleData.Add(test3);

        test4.Label = "mark";
        test4.Value = 8;
        sampleData.Add(test4);

        test5.Label = "james";
        test5.Value = 8;
        sampleData.Add(test5);

        return Json(sampleData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is an example of the piechart I have created. If possible can someone give me an example of how the barchart JSON data should be formatted?

This is the view the JSON data is being inputted into:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    urlDataJSON = '/Home/PieChartJSON';

    $.getJSON(urlDataJSON, "", function (data) {
        var dataSlices = [];
        var dataLabels = "";

        $.each(data, function (entryindex, entry) {
            dataSlices.push(entry['Value']);
            dataLabels = dataLabels + entry['Label'];
        });
        options = {
            legend: { show: true },
            title: 'Poll Results',
            seriesDefaults: {
                // Make this a pie chart.
                renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                rendererOptions: {
                    // Put data labels on the pie slices.
                    // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
                    showDataLabels: true
                }
            }
        }
        var plot = $.jqplot('pieChart', [dataSlices], options);
    });
});
```

And this is the chart i get on the webpage:

EDIT: embedding the screen capture isn't working. So I'll include a link to it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZrYi.jpg

Comment: Can you edit into your question how the `JSON` you are getting looks like? Also useful would be to see how you are using this `JSON` in your `js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see here what you are doing with `dataLabels`. Also I only guess that the thing you do not like about your pie chart is that your legend doesn't show labels, right?

I think you should set your data in a different way. Take a look at one of my other examples related to use of pie chart, [available here](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/NYewy/). 
Effectively, your problem comes down to setting of a pair, first label then value, to each row of your data, like in the linked code:

```
var row = [percentage, count];
data.push(row);
```

Therefore, in your case you would have:

```
var dataSlices = [];
$.each(data, function (entryindex, entry) {
    var row = [entry['Label'], entry['Value']];
    dataSlices.push(row);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Boro. The label part was bugging me and the resource you linked is a big help.
I think I phrased my main question badly however, my big sticking point at the moment is how to structure the bar chart control, I'm still very new to MVC and developing in C# in general.