# How to create a jqplot data array in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, jqplot

I am using ajax to connect to a PHP script and then retrieve the graph coordinates needed for the jqplot jQuery graphing library.

The problem is that I am having difficulties constructing a proper PHP array that can then be converted into a jQuery array that jqplot can read.

Here is the code that retrieves the array from the PHP file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    url: "behind_curtains.php",
    data: {
        monthSelected: month_option_selected
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var stored_data = data;
        alert(stored_data);
    }
});
return stored_data;
}
```

Here is the code that creates the jqplot

```
jQuery.jqplot('chartdiv-data', [], {
    title: 'Plot With Options',
    dataRenderer: stored_data,
    axesDefaults: {
        labelRenderer: jQuery.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            label: "Day",
        },
        yaxis: {
            label: "data"
        }
    }
});
```

If you could please help me create the proper data array in the behind_curtains.php file it would be great!

**Edit 1**
the graphing coordinates array should be in the form of:

```
[[[1,2],[3,5],[5,13]]]
```

and basically I need to somehow write php code that can output an array that stores data in that form.

Thanks

**Solution:**

*behind_curtains.php*

I put together an array that simply generates a string in the form of [[1,2],[3,5],[5,13]]. I then stored the string in a variable and echoed that variable in the form of:

```
echo json_encode($stored_data);
```

On the user side of things here is how my code looked like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:"json",
            url: "behind_curtains.php",
            data: {
                monthSelected: month_option_selected},
            success: function(data){                    
            var stored_data = eval(data) ;  
/* generate graph! */
$.jqplot('chartdiv-weight', [stored_data], {
 title: month, 
axesDefaults: {
    labelRenderer: jQuery.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
  },
  axes: {
    xaxis: {
      label: "Day",
    },
    yaxis: {
      label: "data"
    }
  }   
});
        }
        });
    }
```

`}});</script>`

I hope that helps, if no, whoever is interested please let me know.

Comment: just a tip: you can't "`return`" data after an AJAX call. `stored_data` will be blank when that function returns it.

Comment: Thanks so much, I got rid of it:) (I am very new to ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the `stored_data` but you need to have it declared before the `AJAX` call, like [shown in the bottom most example, here.](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/data-renderers.html) You must also use: `async: false` otherwise you cannot return your data in this fashion. For the same reason if you like you could use `getJSON()` instead.

As it goes to formatting your retrieved data [a similar issue I answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10497512/613495) You need to build your array accordingly to represent your data.

*If you can show how exactly does your `JSON` look like then I could give you a more precise answer.*

Comment: Thank you very much Boro for your answer, I ended up figuring it out!

Comment: @Dmitri it would be very good if you could share with others what was your solution. I see there is at least one person who favors your question it might be of use to him/her to know your solution.